# Ignore repeating values xml 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping, unique-values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<order>
<press_mow>
  <mow_section_id>1</mow_section_id>
    <mow_webs>
        <mow_web>
            <web_number>1</web_number>
        </mow_web>
    </mow_webs>
</press_mow>
<press_mow>
  <mow_section_id>1</mow_section_id>
    <mow_webs>
        <mow_web>
            <web_number>1</web_number>
        </mow_web>
    </mow_webs>
</press_mow>
<press_mow>
  <mow_section_id>2</mow_section_id>
    <mow_webs>
        <mow_web>
            <web_number>1</web_number>
        </mow_web>
       <mow_web>
            <web_number>2</web_number>
        </mow_web>
       <mow_web>
            <web_number>2</web_number>
        </mow_web>
        <mow_web>
            <web_number>3</web_number>
        </mow_web>
        <mow_web>
            <web_number>3</web_number>
        </mow_web>
    </mow_webs>
</press_mow>
<press_mow>
  <mow_section_id>2</mow_section_id>
    <mow_webs>
        <mow_web>
            <web_number>1</web_number>
        </mow_web>
       <mow_web>
            <web_number>2</web_number>
        </mow_web>
       <mow_web>
            <web_number>2</web_number>
        </mow_web>
        <mow_web>
            <web_number>3</web_number>
        </mow_web>
        <mow_web>
            <web_number>3</web_number>
        </mow_web>
    </mow_webs>
</press_mow>
<press_mow>
  <mow_section_id>2</mow_section_id>
    <mow_webs>
        <mow_web>
            <web_number>1</web_number>
        </mow_web>
       <mow_web>
            <web_number>2</web_number>
        </mow_web>
       <mow_web>
            <web_number>2</web_number>
        </mow_web>
        <mow_web>
            <web_number>3</web_number>
        </mow_web>
        <mow_web>
            <web_number>3</web_number>
        </mow_web>
    </mow_webs>
</press_mow>

</order>
```

Trying to create a list of unique mow_webs/mow_web/web_number using menchian grouping however within each press_mow I either get only get 123 once or all numbers within each press_mow unable to see what Im doing wrong any help greatly appreciated.

Desired output

```
1 = 1
1 = 1
2 = 1,2,3
2 = 1,2,3
2 = 1,2,3
```

Have spent hours looking at all the explanations of this method and have previously used to good effect but cannot see what my error is on this occasion. Have tried two different methods below. Can only use xml 1.0. This is my first post apologies in advance if I have made an error.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>

<xsl:key name="webnoB" match="mow_web" use="web_number" />
<xsl:key name="webnoC" match="mow_webs" use="mow_web/web_number" />
<xsl:template match="order">
```

******TESTING HERE********

```
<xsl:for-each select="press_mow">
    SecIdA:<xsl:value-of select="mow_section_id"/>/
    <xsl:for-each select="mow_webs">
        <xsl:for-each select="mow_web[count(. | key('webnoB', web_number)           [1]) = 1]">
            WebNoA:<xsl:value-of select="web_number"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
**************
<xsl:for-each select="press_mow[count(. | key('webnoC', web_number)[1]) = 1]">
    secidB:<xsl:value-of select="mow_section_id"/>/
    <xsl:for-each select="mow_webs">
        <xsl:for-each select="mow_web">
            WebNo.B:<xsl:value-of select="web_number"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
******TESTING HERE********
```

```
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please post the exact result (as code) you expect to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If - as it seems - you want to list the distinct `web_number` values within each `press_mow`, you must include a `press_mow` identifier in the key definition and usage.

And since your input has no unique values identifying the `press_mow` nodes, you will need to use the `generate-id()` function for this.

Consider the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="wn" match="mow_web" use="concat(web_number, '|', generate-id(ancestor::press_mow))" />

<xsl:template match="/order">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="press_mow">
            <section id="{mow_section_id}">
                <xsl:for-each select="mow_webs/mow_web[count(. | key('wn', concat(web_number, '|', generate-id(ancestor::press_mow)))[1]) = 1]">
                    <number>
                        <xsl:value-of select="web_number"/>
                    </number>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </section>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <section id="1">
      <number>1</number>
   </section>
   <section id="1">
      <number>1</number>
   </section>
   <section id="2">
      <number>1</number>
      <number>2</number>
      <number>3</number>
   </section>
   <section id="2">
      <number>1</number>
      <number>2</number>
      <number>3</number>
   </section>
   <section id="2">
      <number>1</number>
      <number>2</number>
      <number>3</number>
   </section>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response I will try this out and update you on my progress. Many thanks

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you. I have to admit I do not understand the  code or how it is working - is it possible to explain the key and the generate id code? Or recommend somewhere I can learn more about how this is working, I have trawled the internet and cannot  get  my head around this... Your help has been greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `generate-id()` function returns a unique id for every node in the input XML. The key combines  the value of `web_number` with the id of its ancestor `press_mow` - thus it is enables us to pick unique values within each `press_mow`. Without this, the Muenchian method would pick unique values within the entire document.